# sync data between two storage accounts in azure

Tags: azure, synchronization, copy, azure-storage

Consider I have two Storage account i,e. Storage 1, Storage 2. When there is an entry to the Storage 1, the entry should be automatically synced to Storage 2 in Azure for all(table, file, blob). Is there anyway?

Comment: Bidirectional? What is the purpose, backup?

Comment: yes for backup purpose

Comment: sync is different than backup. You can use options in answer below, however, if data gets deleted by authorized user, then you also loose data on replica. What do you exactly want?

Comment: @csk Was the answer provided helpful to you ?

Answer (score 1):

As Gaurav mentioned, Redundancy doesn't mean backup, if data is deleted from the original data location, it will replicate and will be deleted from the other locations. If you are specifically looking for backup solutions, I'd recommend checking the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup)

Below are some of the available backup options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of your backup is to make sure you always have data available even in case of a rack/datacenter/region level failure(azure infrastructure failure) then 
we have an option to select a replication strategy when we create a storage account. In this case you would not have access to the backup copy rather these copes are used by Microsoft to recover when a failure is identified.                   These are  -

1. Locally redundant storage (LRS)
2. Zone-redundant storage (ZRS)
3. Geo-redundant storage (GRS)
4. Read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS)

For option 1, 2 and 3 the replica is not available unless Microsoft initiates failover.

Option 4 provides read-only access to the data in the secondary location, in addition to geo-replication( GRS Option 3.)

Not sure if you had a different purpose for taking a backup.

Comment: Replication is not backup! If the data from primary is deleted, it will be deleted from secondary as well.